# Fill a component and bind it to another data type in a form

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, blazor

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75133456/13826315), a decision has been made to remove the second field and when the user enters the **ID** and tabs out, the function will be triggered to get the *name as a string* from a database and fill the text field, but I need the **input box to be bound to the ID** which is an int.

Is that possible?

```
<EditForm EditContext="@editContext">
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" @onblur="lostFocus" />

@code {
private EditContext editContext;
private Patient patient;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new(patient);
    }
    public void lostFocus()
    {
        Patient c = new Patient();
        c = PatientService.GetPatientByStudyID (id);
        
        //code to fill the Input text.
    }
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        if (editContext != null && editContext.Validate())
        {
          PatService.CreatePatient(patient);
          NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Studies",true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user10191234, do you mean the `id` in your `lostFocus` function are received by filling the text input? And the same input also will be filled with name when you search from the database by the `id`?

Comment: @Rena Exactly, the user types the ID, this ID will generate a name, this name should appear, but the binding will still to the ID.

Comment: Hi @user10191234, what I exactly do is to type the id and it will generate a name by this id, and the input will appear the name value. What do you mean for the binding will still to the ID?

Comment: Other fields in this form have `@bind = patient.bed` and similar where `patient` is the model, so I would like stuff like `patient.id`, the be able to validate it at then submit.

Comment: Hi @user10191234, so you want to display this ID input with Name value, but you want to  validate the id when form submit? What's the validation for your ID?

Comment: Hi @user10191234, so you still want to validate the ID although the input has been changed to the name string value?

Comment: Exactly and it will apply to other fields where there is `select` but if this works, I think others can work too..

Comment: Hi @user10191234, If so, I think it seems to be impossible. When you change the input displayed value, it will validate the value(name string) instead of id.  And from your description, it looks like the `select` element, because the `select` element contains `option` with value and text separately. But what you did here is an input, input displays the text with value, cannot do like select element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@bind` to bind the input value and then parse the data to int:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="8" @bind="@CurrentValue" @onblur="lostFocus"/>

@code {
    private EditContext editContext;
    private Patient patient;
    private string CurrentValue { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new(patient);
    }
    public void lostFocus()
    {
        Patient c = new Patient();
        c = PatientService.GetPatientByStudyID(int.Parse(CurrentValue));
        CurrentValue = c.Name;

    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks for the effort, but I need to bind it to `int` and show the string. is that even possible?

Comment: Hi @user10191234, does your code contains a int property named `id` and do you mean you want to bind the filled value to this `id`? If so, just give the value to it `id=int.Parse(CurrentValue)` manually. If you want to dynamically bind and set with different type value, it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be approaching this right.  Or I might be reading this wrong: it won't be the first (or last) time!

Take a look at this.  I've created a custom control for the patient selector that switches between two inputs and has two bind values.  The logic may not be right: I'm making some guesses here.  I've thrown this together so it needs tidying up, but it demonstrates a different approach to the patient selector.

I've missed out validation, etc and the `EditForm` and `EditContext` to keep this simple and your sample code didn't really use it. There's no `InputBase` controls in your code.

A question: How are you controlling form exit when the patient data is dirty?

You can copy and copy the code into a new project.

The data class.

```cs
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? NickName { get; set; }
}
```

And the service with some dummy data

```cs
public class PatientService
{
    private List<Patient> _patients = new ();

    public PatientService() 
    { 
        _patients.Add(new Patient() { Id = 1, Name= "Fred"});
        _patients.Add(new Patient() { Id = 2, Name = "Sally" });
        _patients.Add(new Patient() { Id = 3, Name = "Billy" });
    }

    public async ValueTask<Patient?> GetPatientByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return _patients.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The `PatientSelector` Control.

```cs
if (this.Id is null)
{
    <label>Patient Id</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" value="@this.Id" @onchange=this.OnIdChanged />
        <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=OnNewPatient>Add New Patient</button>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <label>Patient Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@this.Name" @onchange=this.OnNameChanged />
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int?> IdChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> NameChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnIdChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindConverter.TryConvertToInt(e.Value, null, out int value))
            await this.IdChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }

    private async Task OnNameChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => await this.NameChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? null);

    private async Task OnNewPatient()
        => await this.IdChanged.InvokeAsync(0);
 }
```

And the editor:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject PatientService PatientService
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@if (this.patientSectionError)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">There is no patient with that Id</div>
}
else if (this.noPatient)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">You need to enter a patient Id</div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <PatientSelector @bind-Name=patient.Name @bind-Id:get=patientId @bind-Id:set=this.OnPatientIdSet />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <label>Nick Name</label>
        <input disabled="@noPatient" type="text" class="form-control" @bind=this.patient.NickName />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-3 p-3">
    <div class="pb-2">
        ID : @this.patient.Id
    </div>
    <div class="pb-2">
        Name : @this.patient.Name
    </div>
    <div class="pb-2">
        Nick Name : @this.patient.NickName
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Patient patient = new();
    private int? patientId;
    private bool hasPatient => patientId is not null;
    private bool noPatient => !hasPatient;
    private bool patientSectionError;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnPatientIdSet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            this.patient = new();
            this.patientId = 0;
            this.patientSectionError = false;
            return;
        }

        var result = await PatientService.GetPatientByIdAsync(id ?? 0);
        this.patientSectionError = result is null;
        this.patientId = result is null ? null : result.Id;
        this.patient = result ?? new();
    }

 }
```

I've posted my demo project on Github - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO75752205.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the tremendous effort. I will try it.